# Processing an akka stream asynchronously and writing to a file sink

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to write a piece of code that would consume a stream of tickers (stock exchange symbol of a company) and fetch company information from a REST API for each ticker.

I want to fetch information for multiple companies asynchronously.

I would like to save the results to a file in a continuous manner as the entire data set might not fit into memory.

Following the documentation of akka streams and resources that I was able to google on this subject I have come up with the following piece of code (some parts are omitted for brevity):

```
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("stock-fetcher-system")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(None, Some("StockFetcher"))(actorSystem)
  implicit val context = system.dispatcher

  import CompanyJsonMarshaller._
  val parallelism = 10
  val connectionPool = Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[String](s"api.iextrading.com")
  val listOfSymbols = symbols.toList

  val outputPath = "out.txt"  


  Source(listOfSymbols)
    .mapAsync(parallelism) {
      stockSymbol => Future(HttpRequest(uri = s"https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${stockSymbol.symbol}/company"), stockSymbol.symbol)
    }
    .via(connectionPool)
    .map {
      case (Success(response), _) => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Company]
      case (Failure(ex), symbol)       => println(s"Unable to fetch char data for $symbol") "x"
    }
    .runWith(FileIO.toPath(new File(outputPath).toPath, Set(StandardOpenOption.APPEND)))
    .onComplete { _ =>
      bufferedSource.close
      actorSystem.terminate()
    }
```

This is the problematic line:

```
runWith(FileIO.toPath(new File(outputPath).toPath, Set(StandardOpenOption.APPEND)))
```

which doesn't compile and the compiler gives me this mysteriously looking error:

```
Type mismatch, expected Graph[SinkShape[Any, NotInferedMat2], actual Sink[ByeString, Future[IOResult]]
```

If I change the sink to Sink.ignore or println(_) it works.

I'd appreciate some more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler is indicating, the types don't match. In the call to `.map`...

```
.map {
  case (Success(response), _) =>
    Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Company]
  case (Failure(ex), symbol)  =>
    println(s"Unable to fetch char data for $symbol")
    "x"
}
```

...you're returning either a `Company` instance or a `String`, so the compiler infers the closest supertype (or "least upper bounds") to be `Any`. The `Sink` expects input elements of type `ByteString`, not `Any`.

One approach is to send the response to the file sink without unmarshalling the response:

```
Source(listOfSymbols)
  .mapAsync(parallelism) {
    ...
  }
  .via(connectionPool)
  .map(_.entity.dataBytes) // entity.dataBytes is a Source[ByteString, _]
  .flatMapConcat(identity)
  .runWith(FileIO.toPath(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint that the `map` statement returns type `Any` and the sink expects `ByteString`. I actually forgot to delete the `"x"` from the second case statement, but Unit and Company would likely be different than `ByteString` anyways. As to the rest of the answer—writing a `ByteString` to the file changes the semantics of the program as it will not be human readable anymore, secondly what does `flatMapConcat(identity)` do?