# akka streaming file lines to actor router and writing with single actor. how to handle the backpressure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I want to stream a file from s3 to actor to be parsed and enriched and to write the output to other file.
The number of parserActors should be limited e.g
`application.conf`

```
akka{
    actor{
        deployment {
              HereClient/router1 {
                router = round-robin-pool
                nr-of-instances = 28
              }
        }
    }
}
```

`code`

```
val writerActor = actorSystem.actorOf(WriterActor.props())
val parser = actorSystem.actorOf(FromConfig.props(ParsingActor.props(writerActor)), "router1")
```

however the actor that is writing to a file should be limited to 1 (singleton)

I tried doing something like

```
val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](file).withConf(conf).build()

  val source: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed] = AvroParquetSource(reader)
source.map (record =>  record ! parser)
```

but I am not sure that the backpressure is handled correctly. any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed your solution is disregarding backpressure.

The correct way to have a stream interact with an actor while maintaining backpressure is to use the [ask pattern support of akka-stream](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/ask.html) ([reference](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#ask%5BS%5D(parallelism:Int)(ref:akka.actor.ActorRef)(implicittimeout:akka.util.Timeout,implicittag:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BS%5D):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BS%5D)).

From my understanding of your example you have 2 separate actor interaction points:

1. send records to the parsing actors (via a router)
2. send parsed records to the singleton write actor

What I would do is something similar to the following:

```
val writerActor = actorSystem.actorOf(WriterActor.props())
val parserActor = actorSystem.actorOf(FromConfig.props(ParsingActor.props(writerActor)), "router1")

val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =  AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](file).withConf(conf).build()

val source: Source[GenericRecord, NotUsed] = AvroParquetSource(reader)
source.ask[ParsedRecord](28)(parserActor)
      .ask[WriteAck](writerActor)
      .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

The idea is that you send all the `GenericRecord` elements to the `parserActor` which will reply with a `ParsedRecord`. Here as an example we specify a parallelism of 28 since that's the number of instances you have configured, however as long as you use a value higher than the actual number of actor instances no actor should suffer from work starvation.

Once the `parseActor` replies with the parsing result (here represented by the `ParsedRecord`) we apply the same pattern to interact with the singleton writer actor. Note that here we don't specify the parallelism as we have a single instance so it doesn't make sense the send more than 1 message at a time (in reality this happens anyway due to buffering at async boundaries, but this is just a built-in optimization). In this case we expect that the writer actor replies with a `WriteAck` to inform us that the writing has been successful and we can send the next element.

Using this method you are maintaining backpressure throughout your whole stream.

Comment: Thanks, the `WriterAck` must be a `case class` ? because I couldn't do it with `case object`

Comment: @igx the `WriteAck` was just used to make the example more readable. If I had to do something similar I would actually use `Done` as an ack. In any case if you want to use an object you need to use something like `.ask[WriteAck.type]` to specify that you expect a reply of the type of the object `WriteAck`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using one of the "async" operations

Perhaps this other q/a gives you some insperation [Processing an akka stream asynchronously and writing to a file sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638663/processing-an-akka-stream-asynchronously-and-writing-to-a-file-sink?rq=1)